# Setting up the name of a file in the executable directory in C

Tags: c, string

I have to create a buffer to hold the the name of a license file which is in the executable directory. This is my solution (I'm not a C programmer):

```
char buffer[MAX_PATH] = "";
GetModuleFileName(NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH);
int len = (int) strlen(buffer);
buffer[len-7] = '\0';
strcat(buffer,"license.lic");
```

Note I know the name of the executable is net.exe - 7 chars, so I'm cheating.

Firstly is this code safe? I got a compiler warning about using strcat saying I should use strcat_s, but I couldn't get that working.

Secondly how do I get the correct length of the executable name?

Comment: You can pretty safely ignore any compiler warnings telling you to use `*_s`.  I assume you're using Visual Studio.  Basically, the `_s` "safe" functions aren't in reality any better and come with a performance hit.  They are under "Annex K" of the C standard, which is optional to even be supported, which many compilers don't bother with.  Furthermore, the Microsoft implementations of those functions don't even meet the standard set in Annex K, so they aren't even portable with standard-conforming compilers that do implement those functions.

Comment: Well, one amendment I'd make to my previous comment would be to not necessarily *ignore* the warning outright, but make sure that the way you are using the functions such as `strcat` are correct.

Comment: **I'm not a C programmer**. Now you are :)

Comment: Fyi, since you "know" `net.exe` is seven chars wide, the terminator-set and `strcat` are overkill anyway. You could just as easily `strcpy(buffer+len-7, "license.lic");` and be done with it. Just saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is reasonably safe. Assuming `MAX_PATH` is the maximum possible length of a pathname, replacing the executable name with `license.lic` should fit in that size.

Rather than getting the length of the executable name, you can search for the last directory delimiter character, and copy `license.lic` after it. C has a built-in function `strrchr()` for searching a string in reverse.

```
char *sepptr = strrchr(buffer, '\\');
if (sepptr == NULL) {
    sepptr = buffer; // no directory delimiter, replace it completely
} else {
    sepptr++; // point to just past the delimiter
}
strcpy(sepptr, "license.lic"); // Overwrite executable name with license name
```